# What does include_once includes? Variables/functions only or other stuff as well?

Tags: php

I had a file test.php with the following code

```
<?php
//name of this file is test.php
$foo = "some value";
include_once 'extras.php';
$bar = "another value";
echo "test.php: foo is $foo and bar is $bar <br />";
?>
```

Another file with the code

```
<?php
echo "extras.php: foo is $foo and bar is $bar <br />";
?>
```

The output indicates that echo statement from extras.php is included as well in test.php, whereas I being a newbie was assuming that include_once or include constructs only deal with the variables and functions and disregard other stuff. What is correct, guide please.
Thank you

Comment: the include statement copies the content in the specified file into the current file, like merging the too as one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`include_once` includes the entirety of the script into the calling script, *so long as it hasn't been previously included*.  This includes all variables, functions, `echo`s...everything.  In effect, the code is imported into the space where the `include_once` line is, so it is possible to reference variables of an `included`ed script in the calling script.

The script you posted looks like this, after the `include`s are processed:

```
<?php
//name of this file is test.php
$foo = "some value";
echo "extras.php: foo is $foo and bar is $bar <br />";
$bar = "another value";
echo "test.php: foo is $foo and bar is $bar <br />";
?>
```

Just be aware that if the file isn't found, the script doesn't error out, but variables set up in the `include`d script won't be set.  For that, use `require_once`.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of [`include_once`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) as "if the file has not already been included, remove this line and paste the contents of the file here".

There is one to me somewhat strange exception to thinking like this related to variable scope of variables defined in the included file (they will end up in the global scope). More about that [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

Comment: Thanks for such and easy way to understand :)

Answer (score 1):

You better understand `include` and `include_once`

For example, we may take 3 files;

**FUNCTIONS.PHP**

```
<?php
function foo(){
echo 'some code';
}
?>
```

**GLOBALS.PHP**

```
<?php
include('FUNCTIONS.PHP');
foo();
?>
```

**HEADER.PHP**

```
<?php
include('FUNCTIONS.PHP');
include('GLOBALS.PHP');
foo();
?>
```

Now if you try to open `HEADER.PHP` you will get an error because `GLOBALS.PHP` includes `FUNCTIONS.PHP` already. You will get an error saying that `function foo()` was already declared in `GLOBALS.PHP`, and I also included in `HEADER.PHP` - which means I have included `FUNCTIONS.PHP` two times.

So to be sure I only include `FUNCTIONS.PHP` only ONE time, I should use the `include_once()` function, so my `HEADER.PHP` should look like this:

```
<?php
include_once('FUNCTIONS.PHP');
include('GLOBALS.PHP');
?>
```

Now when I open `HEADER.PHP`, I will not get an error anymore because PHP knows to include the file `FUNCTIONS.PHP` only **ONCE**.

So to avoid getting an error, it would just be safe to use `include_once()` instead of `include()` function in your php code.

If you know you are messy with your PHP code, then its safer to use the `include_once()`, but if you keep track of all your code, then its ok to use the `include()` function.

Comment: Thanks man, your answer gave me an insight about include construct as well. Now I am easy bot with include and include_once :)

Comment: I surely wanted to upvote it but I am a new member here and yet not privileged to do so.

Comment: OK.. I saw your profile. But consider an upvote when you get the privilege :)

Answer (score 0):

You should read through [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) and [include_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) function reference in the PHP manual at first. Short story long - both statement basically merge codes in the original / included files, so everything in the included file is run / available in the source file, be it functions, variables, classes, echo statements whatsoever... (however, include_once as the name already suggests includes the file only once, the first time, if it has not been already included, regardless of how many include_once statements you put in there)...